# python could not broadcast input array from shape (144,291,3) into shape (140,300,3)

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a method in python that crops and scales a frame, this one is supposed to insert black bars if the frame is too small for the screen. The problem here lies within the array, for some reason, it just can't fit one into the other and I don't know why. This doesn't happen with every frame, it seems to just happen at one random frame that doesn't have anything special compared to the other frames. It does always happen at the same frame though.

```
def displayFrame(image, csFrame, h, w):
resizedImage = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=csFrame.WScale, fy=csFrame.HScale)
desiredImage = resizedImage[int(csFrame.H * csFrame.HScale):int(csFrame.H * csFrame.HScale + h), int(csFrame.W * csFrame.WScale):int(csFrame.W * csFrame.WScale + w)]
starth = 0
startw = 0
newImage = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8) #If one of the two directions is "zoomed out" too much, black bars will fill in the excess space
if len(desiredImage) < h:
    starth = int(np.floor((h-len(desiredImage))/2))
if (len(desiredImage[0])) < w:
    startw = int(np.floor((w-len(desiredImage[0]))/2))
desiredH = len(desiredImage)
desiredW = len(desiredImage[0])
print("desired:", len(desiredImage[0:desiredH][0:desiredW]), len((desiredImage[0:desiredH][0:desiredW])[0]), "newImage:", len(newImage[starth:(starth+desiredH)][startw:(startw+desiredW)]), len((newImage[starth:(starth+desiredH)][startw:(startw+desiredW)])[0]), "start:", starth, startw)
newImage[starth:(starth+desiredH)][startw:(startw+desiredW)] = desiredImage[0:desiredH][0:desiredW]
return newImage
```

The error happens at the last line before the return. I really don't know why, but it seems like both "DesiredH" and "DesiredW" have different values on these different locations. Neither "newImage" nor "desiredImage" has its boundaries exceeded in this operation. I really don't have a clue why these arrays don't have the same size, just looking at this, they should have the same size since I pass it through what their shape should be like.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pad your tensor with something because shapes don't add up, `144*291*3` is not equal to `140*300*3`. I suggest removing this sample from the dataset.

Comment: Yeah I know the shapes don't match up, it's more of a question why they don't match up. If you have a look at the line that copies the desiredImage into a part of the newImage, it should have the same shape right? It uses desiredH and desiredW in both instances, yet somehow creates arrays of different shapes.

Comment: It should but in python if you have a list `as = 'aaaa'`, if you do `a[:500]` you'll get the same list `as` of length 4. So, this sample is obviously of bad shape and as I said, I suggest you remove it from dataset. If it turns out that you have more samples with this problem, then you should consider other solutions to this problem other than removing all of those samples with different shape.

Comment: Removing it from the dataset is not really an option unfortunatly... I also thought that it might have been because the array simply wasn't big enough, so it took a smaller length, but that seems to not be the case either...

Comment: Try finding the smallest shape in the dataset and change all other data samples to that size.